# Create multiple tables with array variable

Tags: sql, arrays, oracle, loops, create-table

here is the problem.

I read year numbers from a table and insert them in another one (now static but in the end temp table)

Then I look over those numbers and create tables with them.

```
BEGIN 
 INSERT INTO temp_year
  ( year_column )
  ( 
    select extract(year from datum) from datetest
  ); 

FOR counter_id IN ( SELECT * FROM temp_year )
LOOP  
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Create table YEAR_' || counter_id || ' (year int, name char(50))'        
END LOOP; 
END; 
/
```

Temp_year has a column year_column (int) (filled like 2012)
datatest has a date colum with values like 10.02.2012

The result should be a table named YEAR_2012 with columns year int and name char(50)

However this is not working. I quits at the execute immediate part, even when there are years in the temp_year table.

Any ideas??

Thanks in advance.

THeVagabond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Create table YEAR_' || counter_id.year_column || ' (year integer, name varchar2(50))';
```

(Do not miss the semicolon at the end)

Comment: I get: the amount or type of arguments in the call || is wrong (translated from german so it might not be the 100% english error message)

   `Error report:`
   ` ORA-06550: line 10, column 29:`
   ` PLS-00306: Falsche Anzahl oder Typen von Argumenten in Aufruf von '||'`
   ` ORA-06550: line 10, column 11:`
    `PL/SQL: Statement ignored`
   ` 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"`
   ` *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.`

Comment: Sorry, I updated it. Note, you can change error messages to English by `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE = 'AMERICAN';`

Comment: Thanks it is working now. However I get this:

Error report:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
ORA-06512: at line 10
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"
*Cause:    

Why is that so?

Comment: After doing the whole thing with a temp table it is working great. THANKS!